# Как и какие знаки препинания поставить в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие

он долго не мог понять: коля съел пирожное или все же павел

Answer (score 1):

Что значит "как?" Карандашом, ручкой или клавишей.

Кроме отсутствующей прописной в начале предложения и у имён собственных, всё на месте:

*Он долго не мог понять: Коля съел пирожное или все же Павел.*

Главное предложение повествовательное, но автор имеет право сделать его вопросительным.

[Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию.](http://www.fio.ru/pravila/punktuatsiya/znaki-prepinaniya-voprositelnyy-znak/)

Может, у Вас напрашивается запятая, страшно сказать, перед "или"?! Ну нет, ни за что, тут простой выбор между двумя кандидатами на поедание.